# Prove that the intervals $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$ are open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that the intervals $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$ are open in
>   $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm having trouble choosing a radius for every $x \in (a,\infty),\ y\in (-\infty,b)$ such that $B_1(x,r_1)\subset (a,\infty)$ and $B_2(y,r_2) \subset (-\infty,b)$ where both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are open balls.

Comment: Maybe try to make a drawing of what you're trying to do. It might inspire you

Comment: Can we choose it as $\frac{x-a}{2}$? Similarly for the other one.

Comment: @DreaDk Yes. In fact, $x - a$ should also work.

Comment: You don't choose *one* radius for every *x*;  you choose a *different* radius based upon *that* $x$ for *each* $x$.    And the radii you should choose for each $x$ are.... (think about it before you read past the dot, dot, dots) ...... $x-a$ and $b - x$.

Comment: $\frac {x-a}2$ will do but it is smaller than nescessary.  $x - a$ will do just as well (but nothing larger than $x - a$).

Comment: Yeah I know they are different. They are totally dependent on which x we choose that belongs in the intervals.

Comment: Exactly.  so you need a radius $r$ so that $B_r(x) = (x -r , x + r) \subset (a, \infty)$  i.e so that $a \le x - r < x < x+r < \infty$.  Since $x+r < \infty$ always we don't have to worry about that part of the inequality.  But how can we choose $r$ so that $a \le x - r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x\in (a,\infty)$, for any $y >0$ we have $x+y \in (a,\infty)$.
Now, $a<x$, so, exists a $\delta >0$ such that $a<x+\delta\Rightarrow x+\delta \in (a,\infty)$. So, use that $\delta$, and you have the ball centered at $x$ with radius $\delta$ contained in $(a,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at $(a, \infty)$.  We want to show that for every $x \in (a,\infty)$ we can find an $r$ (based on $x$) so that $B(x,r) \subset (a, \infty)$.

Note two things:

1)  $B(x,r) = (x-r, x+r)$

2) $(x-r, x+r)\subset (a,\infty) \iff a \le x-r$ and $x +r \le \infty$.

So we want $a \le x-r$ or  $r \le x -a$.

And that's it.  Any $r$ so that $0 < r \le x-a$ will do.

=====

Proof of 1 (if it isn't imediately obvious)

$B(x,r) = \{y\in \mathbb R: |x - y| < r\}$

$= \{y\in \mathbb R: -r < y - x < r\}$

$= \{y \in \mathbb R: x-r < y < x + r\}$

$= (x-r, x+r)$.

Restatement of 2: $(m,n) \subset (u,v) \iff u \le m$ and $v \ge n$.

Proof of 2 (if it's not immediately obvious)

$(m,n) =\{x \in \mathbb R| m < x < n\}$ so

$(m,n)\subset (u,v)$ means for all $x| m < x < n$ then $u < x < v$

Assuming neither $(m,n)$ nor $(u,v)$ are empty then there exists an $x_0$ so that $m < x_0 < y$ and $u < x_0 < v$.  If $m < u$ then there is a $y$ so that $m < y < u < x_0 < n$ and $y \in (m,n)$ but $y \not \in (u,v)$ which contradicts $(m,n) \subset (u,v)$.  So $m\ge n$.  Similarly $n \le v$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$ are open, is to note that they can be written as a union of open sets, in fact
$$(a,\infty)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a,a+n)$$
and
$$(-\infty,b)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(b-n,b) $$

Answer (score 0):

*A variant*:

- For $x\in (a,+\infty)$, consider the interval centred at $x$: $B(x,x-a)=(a,2x-a)$.
- For $x\in (-\infty,b)$, the interval $B(x, b-x)=(2b-x,b)$.

Note that both intervals have bounds $a$ (resp. $b$) and the symmetric of $a$ (resp. $b$) w.r.t. $x$.